# How can I deserialize a list of different object types in a json config?

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, json-deserialization

I'm using the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` to read config objects from a json file.
But I can't figure out, how to deserialize a `List<BaseClass>` filled with items that derive from the base class.
I assume, you have to store the type of the object somewhere (like [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) in newtonsoft's `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`), but I can't deserialize this.

**Edit:**

Here is an example of what I would like to do. First, the config items:

```
    public abstract class Notifier
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public abstract void Notify(string message);
    }

    public class MailNotifier : Notifier
    {
        public string MailAddress { get; set; }
        public override void Notify(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Send mail with message '" + Name + "' to " + MailAddress);
        }
    }

    public class SmsNotifier : Notifier
    {
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public override void Notify(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Send SMS with message '" + Name + "' to " + PhoneNumber);
        }
    }

    public class NotifierConfig
    {
        public List<Notifier> Notifiers { get; set; }
    }
```

Ideally, I would like to get the config like this:

```
NotifierConfig config = configuration.Get<NotifierConfig>();
```

with the config.json looking something like this:

```
{
  "NotifierConfig": {
    "Notifiers": [
      {
        //"type": "MailNotifier",
        "Name": "MailNotifier_Admin",
        "MailAddress": "admin@somecompany.com"
      },
      {
        //"type": "MailNotifier",
        "Name": "MailNotifier_CEO",
        "MailAddress": "ceo@somecompany.com"
      },
      {
        //"type": "SmsNotifier",
        "Name": "SmsNotifier_Admin",
        "PhoneNumber": "1234567"
      },
      {
        //"type": "SmsNotifier",
        "Name": "SmsNotifier_CEO",
        "PhoneNumber": "7654321"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: How about giving us some example data?

Comment: `config.GetSection("sectionName").Get<List<BaseClass>>()` will most likely get you what you need.

Comment: It hugely depends. If all types have some distinct fields - you can write custom deserializer based on that (both for `System.Text.Json` and `Json.NET`)

Answer (score -1):

We have a function available in `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject)` beside this there is one more overload where you can define your `JsonSerializerSettings`

Comment: I don't want to serialize. I want to deserialize.

Comment: Create classes depicting the same order, `public class NotifierConfig {
public Notifiers notifiers{get;set;} }
public class Notifiers {
public List<Notifier> notifiers{get;set;}}

public class Notifier {
public string Name {get;set;}
public string MailAddress {get;set;} }`

and call the deserializer